# One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0. 0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

when I am running the asp.net project , this error is coming ? how to resolve this ?

I want to run the asp.net program in vs 2017

Comment: sounds like you want to up your .net version.  For some reason it thinks it's 1.0.0.  Alternatively you can go into the package manager and update/revert versions there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can share more details with pictures or error message, then we can help you faster.